# Can Athena's once-per-game activate a Cylon location?

Tags: battlestar-galactica

Sharon "Athena" Agathon (cylon leader) has the ability:

> **Resolute - Action:** Once per game, activate any undamaged location.

Can I use this to activate a Cylon location while infiltrating with Athena?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can.

Look at Louis Hoshi's once-per-game for comparison:

> **Organized - Action:** Once per game, if you are not in the "Brig", activate any 3 undamaged locations, regardless of where you are.  You cannot activate the same location more than once nor any Cylon locations.

Hoshi's ability specifies that you can't activate Cylon locations.  Given Athena's very similar ability does not have this restriction, she can activate them.

Comment: Also, from the official FAQ:
Q: When Athena uses her “Resolute” ability on a New Caprica
location, can she use either the location’s Human Action or the
Cylon Action?
A: Yes.